# Example of libcamera with Qt6 in c++?

Tags: qt, libcamera

I'm trying to build a Qt app on my RPi4 using libCamera in c++, but I keep having build/compile issues. Are there any examples of using libCamera in a Qt app in c++?

I'm using Raspbian bullseye, and Qt6.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add more details. Copy&paste the source code, preferably as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the commands you use to build it and the resulting output/errors/warnings, all formatted as code blocks.

Comment: Question is about existing examples though. Another one, explaining my specific problems can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75993443/dso-missing-from-command-line-with-qmake) though.

Comment: I don't know if there is an example that matches your use case. To me even your use case is not clear enough. Split the problem into smaller ones. Can you build and run a Qt application that does not use `libCamera`? Can you build a minimal non-Qt application that links functions from `libCamera`?